# What are concrete categories with the property that its morphisms that have (functional) inverses are isomorphisms called?

Tags: category-theory

In the category of topological spaces, a morphism (continuous map) which has an inverse (as a function of sets) is not necessarily an isomorphism (homeomorphism), but in the category of groups, or any other algebraic category I can think of, every homomorphisms which has an inverse (as a function of sets) is an isomorphism. What is this property (that the category of groups has and the category of topological spaces does not have) called? And how important is it in Category Theory? Is it a nice property for a category to have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the forgetful functor $U : \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is [conservative](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/conservative+functor). I don't believe this property has a particular name.

[Here you can find some info about how to characterize concrete categories with a conservative functor.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1222237/10014)