# A Lie group homomorphism is an isomorphism iff it is bijective

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, group-homomorphism

I have trouble with the following corollary in John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifolds:

> Corollary 7.6 A Lie group homomorphism is a Lie group isomorphism iff it is bijective.

From my understanding, a bijective homomorphism is an isomorphism and an isomorphism is always bijective. So I don't understand why we need the global rank theorem to prove this.

I've searched online and find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269066/when-is-a-bijective-homomorphism-an-isomorphism) very confusing, which  says that "a bijective homomorphism may not be an isomorphism."  Why? Am I missing something?

Comment: Smoothness is required to be a *Lie* group isomorphism. The post you linked refers to general 'morphisms' in an abstract sense. If you look at morphisms of topological spaces, that are continuous map, it is clear that a continuous bijective map might not be an isomorphism (here, and homeomorphism). To me an isomorphism, you always need to be bijective **and** to have an inverse which is also a morphism

Comment: @Didier So the global rank theorem is used to ensure that the inverse is smooth?

Comment: The algebraic condition being always satisfied for the inverse, yes